# How to fold elements without duplicates into single case class instance?

Tags: scala

Lets say, there's a case class `User`:

```
case class User(id: Int, name: String, habits: Seq[Habit])
```

and another case class `Habit`

```
case class Habit(id: Int, name: String)
```

and a having `habits` seq:

```
val habits = Seq(
  User(1, "user name", Seq(Habit(1, "habit name 1"))),
  User(1, "user name", Seq(Habit(2, "habit name 2"))),
  User(1, "user name", Seq(Habit(1, "habit name 1")))
)
```

I'd like to club the list into a single instance of `User` case class per user id, e.g. `1`, after removing the duplicate habits, e.g. `Habit(1, "habit name 1")` above.

Basically the output should be as follows:

```
User(1, "user name", Seq(Habit(1, "habit name 1"), Habit(2, "habit name 2"))
```

with all habits combined under a single user with no duplicates.

It is guaranteed that `User` objects will have same `user id` and `name`.

Comment: Why not use a Set[Habit] instead of a list?

Comment: Use collections methods such as `groupBy`, `map` etc.

Comment: Have you tried anything? What is the current code that you have and what is the error/problem you see?

Comment: @Daenyth - Set is fine. I have problems with reducing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

May be this is what you want:

```
val users = List(
  User(1, "user name", List(Habit(1, "habit name 1"))),
  User(1, "user name", List(Habit(2, "habit name 2"))),
  User(1, "user name", List(Habit(1, "habit name 1"))))

val result = users.foldLeft(users.head)((r, u) => 
  r.copy(habits = (r.habits ++ u.habits).distinct))
println(result)
// User(1,user name,List(Habit(1,habit name 1), Habit(2,habit name 2)))
```

Comment: This will only work with a single user id. The groupBy solution below does work with multiple user ids.

Comment: It is guaranteed that User objects will have same user id and name.

Answer (score 2):

Using `groupBy` in this manner will give you a `Map[(Int, String), List[User]]`, which assuming the `(id, name)` pairs are unique will allow you to collapse the list of users that belong to each key.

```
list.groupBy(user => (user.id, user.name))
    .map { case ((id, name), duplicates) =>
        User(id, name, duplicates.flatMap(_.habits).distinct)
    }.toList
```

Note that for a list containing multiple users, `groupBy` will not maintain their order.

Answer (score 2):

Since it is guaranteed that all habits belongs to same users, You can

1. FlatMap Users list into one Habits list, then call `distinct`
2. Copy any user (may be `head`), changing the habits into the new merged list

`habits.head.copy(habits=habits.flatMap(_.habits).distinct)`